# Trouble with Galleria image gallery fade and default image

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, gallery, galleria

Using Galleria with frogCMS, but am currentl unable to create fading effects and to display a default image on load (currently only displaying an image on clicking a thumb)

$('ul.gallery').galleria(

onImage(image) { image.css('display','none').fadeIn(); } // not working.

);

// also not working

$('ul.gallery').galleria({

history : true, // activates the history object for bookmarking, back-button etc.
clickNext : true, // helper for making the image clickable
insert : '#main_image', // the containing selector for our main image
onImage : function(image,caption,thumb) { // let's add some image effects for demonstration purposes

// fade in the image & caption

if(! ($.browser.mozilla && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) ) { // FF/Win fades large images terribly slow
image.css('display','none').fadeIn(1000);} 
});
});

Any implimentation help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knocked up a Galleria plugin for a CMS called Indexhibit a few years ago.
[Here's the original thread](http://www.indexhibit.org/forum/thread/1930/) if you're interested.

I believe this should help with default image on load: -

```
$('galleria li:first').addClass('active');
```

Do you have live/static demo to view? Which version did you base your gallery on?
The simple or the advanced version?

Also [checkout the live demo](http://leslieoa.awardspace.com/index.php?/galleria/) I for the above mentioned plugin.
Fadiing/transitions work fine. Feel free to copy+paste what you need.

Hope this helps.